# Assumption tests in discrete-time hazard model

Tags: assumptions, discrete-data, hazard

I am currently working with a random coefficient discrete time hazard model. The following assumptions are subject to this sort of model:

- linear additivity assumption
- proportionality assumption
- no observed heterogeneity assumption

Now I would like to test these assumptions somehow. In the papers I have read so far, these assumptions were always taken as given, and I have not yet seen any standardized tests for them.

Do any standardised tests exist for these assumptions or is rather a matter of the right specification of the model by trying out and comparing the deviance etc. of the different model specifications?